# Mediaelement.js - Would like to Remove ALL Controls - Only Display Video

Tags: mediaelement.js

I am trying to replace my swf header in my webpage with mp4.  I like MediaElement.js but I can't remove the controls.  I don't want to hide the controls, I want to remove them completely... and just display the looping video.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 13):

I think a better solution is:

Set `features` property:

```
features: []
```

Insert this in your css:

```
.mejs-container .mejs-controls { visibility:hidden !important; }
```

That way you can pause-play by clicking the video.

Answer (score 8):

You have to combine those answers:

1. set

   ```
   features: [],
   ```
2. insert this in your css:

   ```
   .mejs-container .mejs-controls {
     display: none !important;
   }
   ```

**Important**

When you do this, you can't pause the video by clicking on it.

Comment: This accepted answer. Point 2 removes black seek shadow.

Answer (score 4):

when you set up the MediaElement options you can set features:

to remove everything just set it to an empty array

```
...
features: ['playpause','progress','current','duration','tracks','volume','fullscreen'],
...

becomes
...
features: [],
...
```

Comment: This just removes the options within the bar but does not remove the bar.  The bar displays with no options in it.  I am trying to remove the bar completely.

Comment: i think you will have to go into the css supplied with mediaelement to remove it or make your own custom css skin.

Answer (score 4):

> Remove the "controls" attribute out of the video tag completely.
>
> Generally in the video tag, any attribute that you want to set to
>   false, should be removed completely instead of setting it to "false"
>   or "".

Careful with removing attributes from within the video tag. Removing the "controls" attribute from the video tag renders a bug in Safari : Safari doesn't play the video anymore. It has something to do with Safari waiting for the controls to be loaded -wether native or not- before authorizing the video to be played.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the "controls" attribute out of the video tag completely.

```
<video id="my-video" preload="auto" width="860" height="650">
```

Generally in the video tag, any attribute that you want to set to false, should be removed completely instead of setting it to "false" or "".